# How to show all users who are in a group - IBM Cognos 10 SDK

Tags: c#, cognos

I want to show all users who are in groups and what role they have.
Now I can list all the users with "//account", all the groups with "//group" or all roles with "//role".

This is how I get all users/groups/roles:

```
propEnum[] props = new propEnum[] {
propEnum.searchPath, propEnum.defaultName,};

sort[] s = new sort[] { new sort() };
s[0].order = orderEnum.ascending;
s[0].propName = propEnum.defaultName;

queryOptions queryOptions = new queryOptions();

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

// Look for all the users.
output.AppendFormat("\nUsers:\n");

searchPathMultipleObject userPath = new searchPathMultipleObject();
userPath.Value = "//account";

baseClass[] bc = cBICMS.query(userPath, props, s, queryOptions);

if (bc.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (baseClass report_item in bc)
    {
        output.AppendFormat("DefaultName:        {0}\n", report_item.defaultName.value);
        output.AppendFormat("SearchPath:         {0}\n", report_item.searchPath.value);
    }
}
```

If I want to show groups instead of users I need just to change `userPath.Value = "//group";` or `.."//role";` for roles.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out how to show the users in the group.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21335459 here is a good description with an example in C# and Java.

I have added "propEnum.members, propEnum.objectClass" to "propEnum[] props" because in ".members" are the user names of the group.

```
propEnum[] props = new propEnum[] {
propEnum.searchPath, propEnum.defaultName, propEnum.members, propEnum.objectClass};
```

I have changed the userPath.Value to "//group" to search for groups.

```
searchPathMultipleObject userPath = new searchPathMultipleObject();
userPath.Value = "//group";
```

Then I have changed my function a little bit:

```
 if (bc.Length > 0)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < bc.Length; i++)
                {
                    string x = bc[i].objectClass.value.ToString();
                    if (bc[i].objectClass.value.ToString().Equals("group"))
                    {
                        group gp = (group)bc[i];
                        baseClass[] members = gp.members.value;
                        if(members != null && members.Length > 0)
                        {
                            for(int j = 0; j < members.Length; j++)
                            {

                                    output.AppendFormat("Members:  {0}\n", gp.members.value[j].searchPath.value); 
                                    output.AppendFormat("DefaultName: {0}\n\n", gp.defaultName.value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```